# I want to print exact word from the command output

Tags: linux, shell-script, grep, telnet

```
telnet test | grep -o Unable
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

Only 'Unable' should be the result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message outputted by `telnet` when it's not able to connect is printed to the standard *error* stream. The standard error stream is by default sent straight to the terminal. You may only pipe the standard *output* stream to some other command (`grep` in this case).

You may send the error stream to the standard output stream by means of a redirection:

```
telnet test 2>&1 | grep -o Unable
```

This would merge the two streams and `grep` would act the merged data stream.

If you want to catch an error condition in `telnet`, it would also be possible to use the utility's exit status:

```
if ! telnet test 2>/dev/null; then
    echo 'something went wrong with telnet'
    exit 1
fi

echo 'telnet ran successfully'
```

This would exit the script if `telnet` returned a non-zero exit status (signalling some sort of failure). I've additionally redirected the error stream to `/dev/null` to discard it completely.

Answer (score 4):

It looks that the message is printed to stderr so do this:

```
telnet test 2>&1 | grep -o Unable
```

In bash and ZSH you can also use `|&`:

```
telnet test |& grep -o Unable
```

Comment: I was going to say something very similar, but to me that's the simplest one